# Unity: Messages in Compound Colliders

Tags: unity, 2d, collider

Lets say I have a 2D character with two colliders: a circle collider that represents the feet, and a box collider that represents the body. Lets say that the character is currently standing on the ground, i.e. only the feet collider is in contact with the ground collider. According to the Unity manual, I will receive an [OnCollisionEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) message. That message contains a [Collision2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D.html) object that contains an [otherCollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D-otherCollider.html) field of type [Collider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html). I don't see anything in that object that would tell me which of the two colliders - the body or the feet - initiated the message.

So my question is this: how do you figure out which collider in a compound collider initiated a collision/trigger message?

Comment: But that field is described as "The incoming Collider2D involved in the collision with the otherCollider", so my interpretation is that "collider" is the collider that hit this object. 

But again, the question stands: what property denotes which collider was involved? The collider field is also a Collider2D object, which as I said does not seem to have a way to differentiate colliders.

Comment: `if( myCircleCollider == collision.collider )` or `if( myCircleCollider == collision.otherCollider )` both don't do it for you?

Comment: I suppose that would work... Didn't think to compare by object id...